# Is it okay if I make a VCC loop underneath a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, power

Is this way okay?

[image: VCC Loop]

Or is this way better?

[image: VCC with terminated]

With loop, the power impendence should be lower, but it might become an antenna if decoupling is not good enough.

Without loop, the pin at the end of VCC line might have lower voltage than others.

Which one is better?

Edited: This is a two layer board.

Edited again: I have decided to remove the loop and thick up the track, thanks.

Comment: The loop seems to be the better antenna to me. But this is all happening on a dedicated power plane in 4 layer board, right?

Comment: It is a two-layers board.

Comment: The ring seems OK as long as it doesn't cut off any other routes you need to make. But in that case, why not fill the whole area with VCC copper?

Comment: If you have enough space on the top layer, and want to make your life easier, put the bypass cap on the top layer. Also be careful with via close to the pins as it can results in production issues.

Comment: Have you considered a star layout?

Comment: You could also just fill the loop in to form a mini power plane under the IC

Comment: Thicken up the track except for the stubs to the actual pads.

Comment: Why can't you just make it a giant pad?

Comment: Which microcontroller is it?

Comment: It is STM32G473